# What are some 2D mobile game engines?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, game-engine, 2d-games

I'm planning to work on a big project for the next year or so. It's going to be a platform-based mobile game and I'm looking for some good game engines I could start working with.

I am experienced with AppGameKit, which works perfectly - however, I'm looking for something where I can work with graphics a bit more.

The graphics capabilities are the most important for us - we want to use a lot of particles, lighting, shadows etc. Is there any code-based (not drag-and-drop) game engine similar to AGK, but with better graphics capabilities, optimally with PC build support, too?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can also try Unreal Engine. It has many starter templates including platformers. It provides both code-based and drag&drop programming options. Moreover, you can make awesome graphic effect with Unreal if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think now cocos2d-x is a good way.
At cocos2d-x, we can create particle effects and modify them.
Now, cocos2d-x also supports many things (includes lighting, shadows, 3D models...) with high performance.
cocos2d-x is open source and I think we can control rendering.

now I'm using cocos2d-x to make games, and I can control some simple particles, shapes. I think it will help you too :D

Comment: Thanks, will check it out(:

Answer (score 1):

**Unity** is not bad. 2D games is ok, but it's greater for 3D games.

If you are good at **C#** or **javascript** than **C++**, you should choose Unity.

Comment: Thanks, I had a few shots with it before, didn't really like the drag-and-drop interface, but I'll have another look, it was a pretty long time ago. :)